# Implementing where expression to haskell interpreter

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am trying to add where expression eval to my interpreter. My current data types and eval methods are below.

```
data Exp = IntExp Integer
         | IntOpExp String Exp Exp
         | WhereExp Exp [(String, Exp)]
         | VarExp String
   deriving(Show,Eq)

type Env = [(String, Val)]

data Val = IntVal Integer
         | ExnVal String
   deriving(Show, Eq)



eval :: Exp -> Env -> Val
eval (IntExp i) _ = IntVal i

eval (IntOpExp op e1 e2) env = 
    let v1 = eval e1 env
        v2 = eval e2 env
        Just f = lookup op intOps
     in liftIntOp f v1 v2


eval (LetExp var e1 e2) env =
  let v1 = eval e1 env
   in eval e2 (insert var v1 env)
```

Currently, I have had the approach of where clause working similar to let clause, but for multiple expressions, thus made this implementation :

```
--For empty pattern (WhereExp _ []) _ :

eval (WhereExp e1 []) env = eval e1 env

--For single element case

eval (WhereExp e1 [(var, e2)]) env =
    let v2 = eval e2 env
        in eval e1 (insert var v2 env)
```

Which works for single-element lists of (var,e2) such as :

```
ghci> eval (WhereExp (VarExp "x") [("x",(IntExp 0))]) []
(IntVal 0)

ghci> eval (IntOpExp "*" (VarExp "z") (WhereExp (IntOpExp "-" (VarExp "x") (VarExp "y")) [("y",(IntExp 5))])) [("x", (IntVal 12)), ("z", (IntVal (-4)))]
(IntVal (-28))
```

But does not cover patterns like below :

```
(WhereExp _ ((_, _):_:_)) _
(WhereExp _ []) _
```

where multiple (var,e) elements exist in the list.
Such a case, for example, is below, which gives non-exhaustive patterns

```
eval((WhereExp (IntOpExp "+" (VarExp "x") (VarExp "y")) [("x",IntExp 10),("y",IntExp 12)],[]),IntVal 22)
```

I am kind of lost on how to approach a list of (var,e) pairs to implement this pattern to my where clause. Any help is much appreciated! Thank you.

Edit:
Based on the chi's answer, which was very helpful for me to understand what to do, I have made some progress and providing my current state below. I have utilized a helper function for implementing. But I still can not seem to cover the pattern :

```
(WhereExp _ ((_, _):_:_)) _
```

Further advices would be appreciated. Thank you !

```
helperEvaluator :: [(String,Exp)] -> Env -> [(String,Val)]
helperEvaluator xs cur_env = map (\(a,b) -> (a,eval b cur_env)) xs


eval (WhereExp e1 ((var, e2):xs)) env = eval e1 new_env
    where
        --helperEvaulator xs cur_env = map (\acc (a,b) -> (a,eval b cur_env)) xs
        --new_list = helperEvaulator [(var, e2)] env 
        new_env = foldr ((\(var1,v1) -> (insert var1 v1))) (env) (helperEvaluator ((var, e2):xs) env)
```

Comment: The last three equations in `where` must be indented exactly in the same way. Also, turn on warnings: you are discarding `acc`, which should be reported as a warning.

Comment: I have fixed all the syntax issues but still can not perform the pattern matching. Can not really understand why.

Comment: Your last `WhereExp` pattern should cover all cases except for `WhereExp e1 [])`, so I can't see what's wrong.

Comment: I think it's better to ask a new, followup question, including the latest code and link to this question for background. one question at a time. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume `where` bindings can not be recursive, like your `let` ones.

So, we have `WhereExp e1 bindings` where `bindings :: [(String, Exp)]`. We can proceed as follows.

- First, we recursively evaluate all the `Exp`s in that list. We can use `map ... bindings` for that, where the `...` function calls `eval` suitably. This produces a list of evaluated bindings `[(String, Val)]`.
- Then, we have to `insert` these values in `env`. That is, from the list `[(str1, val1), (str2, val2), ...]` we want to compute `insert str1 val1 (insert str2 val2 .... env)`.
- Finally, using the modified environment, we can evaluate `e1`.

Comment: I understood what to do based on your answer, which was very helpful. Thanks. But I'm now having a hard time implementing it due to syntax issues. Could you take a look at my progress and give some insight? Thank you again.